# Settings object has no attribute DATABASE

Tags: python, scrapy

Using scrapy to scrape a website. When I try to run the crawler, I receive an error that the settings object doesn't have an attribute DATABASE. This is after I have added the Database attribute to my settings.py file.

This is the settings.py code

```
BOT_NAME = 'teamblind'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['teamblind.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'teamblind.spiders'

DATABASE = {

    'drivername' : 'xxxxx',
    'host' : 'xxxxx',
    'port' : xxxx,
    'username' : 'xxxx', 
    'password' : 'xxxxx',
    'database' : 'xxxxxx'

}
```

The following is the models.py

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL


from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


DeclarativeBase = declarative_base()

def db_connect():

    settings = get_project_settings()
    return create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))


#creates a table
def create_posts_table(engine): 

    DeclarativeBase.metadata.create_all(engine)


#creates a post for a table 
def create_posts(DeclarativeBase):

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = Column('title', String)
    views = Column('views', String)
    comments = Column('comments', String) 
    likes = Column('likes', String)
    link = Column('link', String)
```

This is the code for the pipelines -

```
from .models import create_posts, db_connect, create_posts_table


class TeamblindPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):

        engine = db_connect()
        create_posts_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        
        session = self.Session()
        post = create_posts(**item)
        

        try:
            session.add(post)
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise 
        finally:
            close()

        return item
```

This is my items.py

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class TeamblindItem(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    title = Field()
    views = Field()
    comments = Field()
    likes = Field()
    link = Field()
```

Finally, this is the spider -

```
import scrapy
#from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
#from teamblind.items import TeamblindItem


#define the spider class for scraping data from teamblind.com 

class TeamBlindReferrals(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'teamblind'

    
    #define the start_requests methods to iterate and generate request objects from the start urls
    def start_requests(self):

        urls = ['https://www.teamblind.com/topics/Referrals']

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)


    #define the parse function to extract data from the website 
    def parse(self, response):

        posts = response.css('li.word-break')

        for item in posts:

            yield{

                'title': item.xpath('//a/@title').get(),
                'views': item.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'view')]//text()").get(),
                'comments': item.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'comment')]//text()").get(),
                'likes': item.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'like')]//text()").get(),
                'link': item.xpath("//li/a//@href").get()
            }
```

When I run the spider I get the following error, please help in resolving this.

```
2020-08-12 06:15:11 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arif/scrapy_practice/ScrapeProj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/Users/arif/scrapy_practice/ScrapeProj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 87, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/Users/arif/scrapy_practice/ScrapeProj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 101, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/Users/arif/scrapy_practice/ScrapeProj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "/Users/arif/scrapy_practice/ScrapeProj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/Users/arif/scrapy_practice/ScrapeProj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/Users/arif/scrapy_practice/ScrapeProj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 35, in from_settings
    mw = create_instance(mwcls, settings, crawler)
  File "/Users/arif/scrapy_practice/ScrapeProj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 156, in create_instance
    instance = objcls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/arif/scrapy_practice/teamblind/teamblind/pipelines.py", line 16, in __init__
    engine = db_connect()
  File "/Users/arif/scrapy_practice/teamblind/teamblind/models.py", line 14, in db_connect
    return create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'DATABASE'
```

Comment: What is `SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE` set to? https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#designating-the-settings

Comment: @NikolasStevenson-Molnar it is set to nothing, I have this in my scrapy.cfg file - [settings]
default = teamblind.settings

Comment: Also, what value do i need to assign to it? And which file does the SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE go into? I don't see that in the docs. Thanks

Comment: What if you use `settings['DATABASE']`?

Comment: @Gallaecio it returns a `TypeError` unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: Where does that new error come from?

Comment: When i use `settings['DATABASE']`.

Comment: @Arif According to the docs, `SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE` is an environment variable. So set it before running your script.